# Why doesn't the simple function works?

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a simple function in an angularjs controller, to turn on/off a bool variable, but it doesn't work? Why?

```
app.controller("registrationCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.wasSubmitted = false;
    $scope.showInfo = true;

    $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.wasSubmitted = true;
    };

    $scope.switch = function () {
        if ($scope.showInfo == true) {
            $scope.showInfo = false;
        } else {
            $scope.showInfo = true;
        }
    };
});
```

The function is used like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="switch()">Show/Hide</button> {{showInfo}}
```

Comment: have you defined that "$scope.showInfo" in controller ?? or directly using in this function ?

Comment: Can you share a working demo that describes your problem?

Comment: Use ng-click instead of onclick

Comment: ng-click is correct, thank very much

Answer (score 3):

Use ng-click:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="switch()">Show/Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem in the view. Instead of `onclick` it is necessary to use `ng-click`:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="switch()">Show/Hide</button> {{showInfo}}
```